# Can you use unnamed, one-line objects in VB.NET without passing them as arguments or something?

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I thought I remembered using unnamed, one-line objects in VB.NET without passing them as arguments or anything.  For instance:

```
New SqlCommand("some string", someSqlConnection)
```

does not compile, and neither does this:

```
(New SqlCommand("some string", someSqlConnection))
```

In the second case, the added parantheses will allow you to call functions on that object and pass their return values as arguments to other functions, but it doesn't work when the object or one of its functions is not being used as an argument to another function.

However this does compile:

```
someFunction(New SqlCommand("some string", someSqlConnection))
```

Is there a way to get around that restriction?  In other words, without wrapping function calls around them or adding more lines of code?  If not, I wonder why this would've been left out of the language?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Are the first two statements not exactly the same? If the first one doesn't compile, why would the second one compile?

Comment: I forgot to include the parentheses earlier, and I added some text to go along with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I can think of *why* anyone would want to do this (create an instance without assinging it to a variable) is if you're interessted in a side-effect caused by the constructor. If this is the case, it does not hurt to actually create a variable like `Dim tmp = New MyObject()` (what does hurt is a constructor with side-effects, but that's another topic).

If, however, you're going to call a method on that object, you can use the `Call` statement, like

```
Call New SqlCommand("foo", someSqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery()
```

`Call` is requiered here because the expression doesn't start with an identifier.

Using `Call` is your friend here, as long as you actually call a method on your new object. 
And since each object provides a `ToString` method, you could always use `Call New Foo().ToString()` to create an instance of `Foo` in one line without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: It works if you call a method, but there's no real way to do this for just using the constructor?  (I was mostly looking into it for calling a method.)

Comment: No, it's not possible for just using the constructor. The benefit of allowing this is small, and a workaround is plain easy, so I wouldn't expect this in a future version of VB.Net.

Comment: @Panzercrisis out of curiosity, how would it benefit you to be able to use Call on the constructor alone?

Comment: There wouldn't be any use with just the constructor that I'd be interested in, unless somebody coded things awkwardly.

Answer (score 4):

Your code won't compile because there is absolutely no point in calling a class constructor if you are not assigning the created instance on anything or passing it down to a method.

If you are asking on how to both declare and instantiate a variable on one line, this is how:

```
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("some string", someSqlConnection)
```

Afterwards you can use the `myCommand` pointer (which is the "return value" of a constructor) as an argument to other functions.

Otherwise, I would suggest that you use a shared method somewhere in a class instead:

```
Public Shared Function ExecuteNonQuery(connection As IDbConnection, query As String) As Integer
    Using cmd As IDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = query
        cmd.Connection = connection
        Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Function
```

Afterwards all you would have to do is this:

```
myClass.ExecuteNonQuery("my sql query", someSqlConnection)
```

This way you'll get your one-liner, referenceless query executer. Better yet: this will work with any existing ADO.NET implementation, be it Sql Server, OLEDB, ODBC, Oracle, MySql or any others.

If you add the [`Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to the above method, you could even do:

```
someSqlConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("my sql query")
```

Comment: @downvoter, please do not keep your wisdom to yourself. Share it with the world. Thanks.

Comment: You would think this should be allowable, without it being passed as an argument to another function: `(New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('someString')", someSqlConnection)).ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: That would still be wrong because your command object wouldn't be disposed afterwards.

Comment: In other garbage-collected languages, stuff like that wouldn't be a problem.  The GC would be able to just pick up the anonymous object on its next run, and it would perform necessary cleanup.  Does the .NET one run differently, making it a risk in this case that the object might get eliminated without cleanup?

Comment: @Crono I think it should be garbage-collected soon instead, since no one holding reference to it. Anyway, this code : `(new SqlCommand()).ExecuteNonQuery();` compiled in C# but it's VB.NET version doesn't : `(New SqlCommand()).ExecuteNonQuery()`. Btw, I'm not the one that responsible for explaining downvote.

Comment: I personnally am not comfortable with such coding patterns (I *much* prefer calling `Dispose` explicitely), but I guess at this point it's a matter of preferences. Still, I believe my answer has merit and should not be voted down.

Comment: @Panzercrisis The object will be collected just fine. The point is that it is good practice (and often essential) to call `Dispose` on each object that implements `IDisposable`. It's an implemention detail that it does not matter for `SqlCommand`, but it sure does for e.g. `SqlConnection`, since it uses unmanaged ressources that are not cleaned up by the garbage collector (hence they're called *unmanaged* ressources).